# Hide text by degrading like Google play does

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the same effect link https://play.google.com/store does within the title of an item.

If you have a look at any title which is larger than the div width, at the end you see how it become transparency till it's confused with the white background.

I wonder how can I accomplish this effect?

Can I use CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like they are overlaying a `<span>` tag that has a gradient background from transparent to white. Inspect `span.paragraph-end` in your browser's developer console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @showdev mentioned, it's just a span element over the  tags end. (CSS copied from the site with few modifications.

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative; 
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  max-height: 36px;
  min-height: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)),color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
  background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25px;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mqLy2uuy/1/